# Infile Outputting only 1 line

Tags: java, file, file-io, output

My outer loop to control reading the data file is not correct, can someone explain to me how to get the loop to print the entire data file and not just the first word in the data file?

```
public static void display() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader("G:\\DataFileDS.txt")); 
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(infile.nextLine());
    StringElement str = new StringElement();

    while(token.hasMoreTokens()) {
        str.setString(token.nextToken());
        stringList.insert(str);
    }

    stringList.print();

    int n = stringList.listSize();
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        System.out.println(stringList.retrieveAt(i) + " " + stringList.retrieveAt(i+1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the while loop runs first and once it finishes, it prints the value. Then your for loop runs only once as listsize is probably one. 
Try printing list size. Since I cant test this code.

It might be this way:

```
public static void Display()throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
   {
      Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader("G:\\DataFileDS.txt")); 
      StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(infile.nextLine());
      StringElement str = new StringElement();

      while(token.hasMoreTokens())
      {
         str.setString(token.nextToken());
         stringList.insert(str);
         int n = stringList.listSize();
         for(int i=0; i<n-1; i=i+1)
         {
            System.out.println(stringList.retrieveAt(i) + " " + stringList.retrieveAt(i+1));
         }
          stringList.print();
      }


   }
```

Comment: It must be something more than that, although your difference in code got it to output three times, but three times with the same name repeated. Any other suggestions before I deconstruct this part and build my way back up?

Comment: what does listsize print?

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: Link nt found and earlier you therr were other issues. plz check the link again.. i can't test otherwise

Comment: @user3604953 you have dozens of errors there.. can you please debug so I can test wht u have asked for specifically

Comment: @user3604953 how does your data file look like?

Comment: those errors are because the classes I use are source codes from a file. I would have to upload all of them to the same place and run again for them to go away.

Comment: In order for me to test it, you have to otherwise makes no point of testing

Comment: http://ideone.com/5crbEB  this is the code with data file. I will post source codes next

Comment: Ok, I have attached where the entire is located with source codes in it. Go to the site quickmednotes.com/mcliett , click on StackOverflow.zip and you will find the program named Program5final and you can run it from there and the data file is names DataFileDS. Thanks so much !